# Failed to check share space via recorded path form sql database by powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, network-share

Could anybody tell me why I failed on these code?

1, I connect to database
2, I query useful information from database (get path)
3, I checked the free space under queried path

Here are my codes:

```
######connect to windows authentication local database################################

$connection= new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection #Set new object to connect to sql database

$Connection.ConnectionString ="server=.;database=sharespace;trusted_connection=True" # Connectiongstring setting for local machine database with window authentication

Write-host "connection information:"

$connection #List connection information

Write-host "connect to database successful."

$connection.open() #Connecting successful

#########query drop paths############################################################

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand #setting object to use sql commands

$SqlQuery = "select Droppath from sharespace" #setting query "get drop paths"

$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery # get query

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter #

$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd #

$SqlCmd.Connection = $Connection

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 

#$Connection.Close()

$DataSet.Tables[0].rows[1]
#############check free space form drop paths###########################################


$var=$dataset.tables[0].rows[1]  #
#$var.system.data.datarow

$var.droppath

$map = new-Object -com wscript.Network 

$map.mapNetworkDrive("v:",$($var.droppath))

$fso = new-Object -com Scripting.FileSystemObject

$do = $fso.getdrive("v:")

$do.AvailableSpace

$do.TotalSize

#$var|get-member

$map.RemoveNetworkDrive("v:")

$Connection.Close()
```

I am sure the path I queried is valid cause I test this path by using cmd. But I failed here.... error logs are :

```
  Exception calling "MapNetworkDrive" with "2" argument(s): "The network location     cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help."
  At D:\checkfreespace.ps1:47 char:21
  + $map.mapNetworkDrive <<<< ("v:",$($var.droppath))
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

  Exception calling "GetDrive" with "1" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0044 (CTL_E_DEVICEUNAVAILABLE)"
  At D:\checkfreespace.ps1:51 char:20
  + $do = $fso.getdrive <<<< ("v:")
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

  Exception calling "RemoveNetworkDrive" with "1" argument(s): "This network connection does not exist."
  At D:\checkfreespace.ps1:59 char:24
  + $map.RemoveNetworkDrive <<<< ("v:")
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error occurs:

> `$map.mapNetworkDrive <<<< ("v:",$($var.droppath))`
>
> The network location     cannot be reached

So what it the value of `$var.droppath`, and is it accessible outside this script?

Comment: I tried $var.droppath at the very begainning, this failed either. I think the path is ok since I have test it via cmd, it is accessible.

Comment: @Pansal: Try just that part of the script (mapping the drive) with a hardcoded path in PSH: does it work?

Comment: :I tried that part with the path like this:$map.mapNetworkDrive("v:", "\\network\dirves\test1") . It works.

Comment: @Pansal: I can be very confident then that either this is a permissions problem (is the script scheduled?). Or (and more likely): you are *not* passing the string you think you are to `mapNetworkDrive`. Have you tried using ISE's debugger to break at that line and examine precisely what is being passed? (General principle of debugging: if you *know* what you are passing and therefore is *must* work then you are wrong in both respects. Debugging is about overcoming your own assumptions.)

Comment: I tried to use debugger and the debugline pointed to the line '49', which just after the line '$map.mapNetworkDrive("v:",$($var.droppath))'. So I think all the codes upper it are fine. I dont understand why these code could pass with hardcoded path but failed with $.

Comment: I got!!! I know why fault happened here!!The path I got from database was followed a lot of "spaces"! so $map.mapNetworkDrive("v:", "\\network\dirves\test1") worked, while $map.mapNetworkDrive("v:", "\\network\dirves\test1        ")failed!Now I am looking for some solution to drop these spaces from SQL server table I use.

Comment: @Pansal: To remove spaces in PSH uses the `TrimEnd` method: `$path = $var.droppath.TrimEnd()` and then pass `$path` to `mapNetworkDrive`.